# Rails5 - Using Controller Helper to build Timeline Chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts

I'm trying to build a timeline chart that resembles a Gantt Chart from softwares such as Jira - To do this I am trying to pass the [Google Charts 'Timeline' Module](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) 4 parameters from a helper. I was using ChartKick for this, but it could not fascilitate any of the optional parameters that the Timeline module allows.

**Current Helper**

```
  def get_all_tasks
    tasks = @project.tasks
    sorted = tasks.order(:task_start_date)
    sorted_task_array = []
    sorted.each do |s|
      sorted_task_array << [s.product, s.task_name, s.task_start_date, s.task_end_date]
    end
    sorted_task_array.to_s.gsub('"', "'")
  end
```

This will output an array such as

```
[[Product, Comment, Thu, 02 Feb 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00, Tue, 02 May 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00], ...]
```

Minified for brevity, but the arrays are outputting the the Rails time format(my fault, I know).

So I modified it to be  `s.task_start_date.strftime("%F")` and I have actually tried quite a few options on the [strftime docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

What's weird is I ALSO tried hard-coding the format that new Date() would have output.

AKA

```
> new Date(1789, 3, 30)
1789-04-30T04:00:00.000Z
```

And I still have 'invalid number' on the datetime field.

Hard-coding their example, or any example using `new Date()` seems to work, so what am I missing? I'm not sure how I could handle this without doubling the work in JS - When Rails can convert it.

**Chart JS - Basic from the example**

```
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(
        <%= get_all_tasks %> 
        )
    var options = {
      timeline: { groupByRowLabel: false }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

Thoughts?

**Update**

I found out to get the time in the format I need, I would use `s.task_end_date.iso8601` - However, I am still getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` on the timing.

With this new error I'm thinking it may be due to my `gsub` that is removing the double quotes, but without removing the quotes I get an error on `&` that is output in the `&quot;` section of the JS.

**Update 2 - Format**

I realized my decimal was off, and after comparing the docs I saw I can append the amount of miliseconds to `iso8601`.

I now have `s.task_start_date.iso8601(3) , s.task_end_date.iso8601(3)` which is returning the same exact format as new Date(), but I am still getting a rejection due to :

`Value 2017-02-02T00:00:00.000Z does not match type date in column index 2`

Comment: You can just do `tasks.order(:task_start_date).pluck(:product, :task_name, :task_start_date, :task_end_date).to_json` instead.

Comment: @max Wow - I didn't even think about using pluck like this. Will make use of it in multiple helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, I had to have JavaScript do the heavy lifting.

I used the helper to return the data in an array and used `strftime` to put the datetime as I wanted.

```
  def get_all_tasks
    tasks = @project.tasks
    sorted = tasks.order(:task_start_date)
    sorted_task_array = []
    sorted.each do |s|
      sorted_task_array << [s.product, s.task_name, s.task_start_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d") , s.task_end_date.strftime("%Y, %m, %d") ]
    end
    sorted_task_array
  end
```

I then had JavaScript handle the wrapping.

```
var data = <%= raw get_all_tasks %>;
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      var row = []
      for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
          row.push(data[i][j]);
      }
       for (j=2; j < 4; j++){
          row.push(new Date(data[i][j]));
      }
      result.push(row);
  }
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(
        result 
        )
    var options = {
      timeline: { groupByRowLabel: false }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
</script>
```

The magic happens at the top, but it's working perfectly now.

Thanks to @[max's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) comment in the question I have modified the helper to be much simpler:

```
  def get_all_tasks
    @project.tasks.order(:product, :task_start_date).pluck(:product, :task_name, :task_start_date, :task_end_date).to_json
  end
```

Comment: Your should declare `var i, j;` at the top. As currently written they are implied globals.

Comment: @max Good catch - Fixed. Thanks.